# How to upload a .xlsx file to jenkins job

Tags: excel, jenkins, file-upload, jenkins-plugins

How can I upload a .xlsx file to jenkins job as a build parameter.?

I tried using the file parameter but I see that the file is losing its extension or the original format.

Is there any way I can upload an excel file to the jenkins job from jenkins UI?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file parameter settings, name the file with .xlsx extension:
[image]
Then the file should hade that extension in your workspace.