# Jenkins / Upload file to Jenkins machine

Tags: jenkins

I try to upload file to my jenkins machine.

I try to use the File Parameter option, and put in the File location line:`/opt/myFolder`.

I wish that if I'll choose `a.txt` file from my local machine, then it will be uploaded to `/opt/myFolder/a.txt`.

But it gives me an error: `FATAL: /opt/myFolder (Is a directory)`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here, [How to upload a .xlsx file to jenkins job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258628/how-to-upload-a-xlsx-file-to-jenkins-job/42258724#42258724). Basically the name you enter in the `File Parameter` setting will be the name of the file, so in your case you have set File location to be `/opt/myFolder`, however it should be the actual file location, so `/opt/myFolder/a.txt`. This do however mean that the file will have the same name each time.

And as **Christopher Orr** points out in the comments, the file location should be a relative URL so that it is loaded into the workspace, that way it won't hinder you from running jobs in parallel and on different machines.

Comment: Though you should prefer, like the inline documentation for file parameter says, to use a relative path, i.e. keep the uploaded file within the build workspace.

Comment: That is true, thanks! I've updated my answer so that it clarifies that (and why).